# $f$ is concave if and only if $\left\{(x,y):y\leq f(x)\right\}$ is a convex set, how?

Tags: calculus, optimization

> **Definition:**
>    A real valued function $f$ defined on a convex subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is **concave** if for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ in $U$ and for all $t$ between $0$ and $1$, $$f(t\mathbf x+(1-t)\mathbf y)\geq tf(\mathbf x)+(1-t)f(\mathbf y).$$
>   A real valued function $g$ defined on a convex subset $U$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is **convex** if for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ in $U$ and for all $t$ between $0$ and $1$, $$g(t\mathbf x+(1-t)\mathbf y)\leq tg(\mathbf x)+(1-t)g(\mathbf y).$$
>   A set $U$ is a **convex set** if whenever $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are points in $U$, the line segment joining $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$,$$\mathcal l(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\left\{t\mathbf x+(1-t)\mathbf y):0\leq t\leq 1 \right\},$$ is also in $U$.

Now, the assertion is $f$ is concave if and only if $\left\{(x,y):y\leq f(x)\right\}$ is a convex set, and similar for convex function.

How are these true?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, oh, really sorry, Sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is a concave function, then for any $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in S := \{(x,y) : y\leq f(x)\}$, and any $t \in [0,1]$, note that
$$
ty_1 + (1-t)y_2 \leq tf(x_1) + (1-t)f(x_2) \leq f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)
$$
Hence, $(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2, ty_1 + (1-t)y_2) \in S$, and so $S$ is convex.

Conversely, if $S$ is convex, and $x,y \in U$, and $t \in [0,1]$, then you want to show that
$$
f(tx+(1-t)y) \geq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y)\qquad\qquad(\ast )
$$
Note that $(x,f(x)), (y,f(y)) \in S$, and hence
$$
(tx + (1-t)y, tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)) \in S
$$
which precisely gives you $(\ast )$. So $f$ is concave.

Comment: So amazing you are, Sir! Thank you.